# convert to e-notation maximizing number of significant figures with constrained number of decimals

Tags: floating-point

I'm looking to convert a number to e-notation with no more than 3 decimals.
I don't know the sign of the input and it might be an integer.
I also want to maximize the number of significant figures.
The number is always in base_10.
It might be negative.
The total number of figures (integral+fractional) never exceeds 18.
I code in an un-typed environment that doesn't differ between integer and float.

```
Example 1: 0.001587301587 becomes 1587301.587E-9 
Example 2: 0.25 becomes 0.25
```

So the code should select two things: number of decimals and exponent in order do maximize the number of significant figures.
The number of decimals must not exceed 3.

---

Initially I did this by converting the input to a string, counted the position of the decimal point from the right. Then I moved the decimal point and divided the new number by the original to figure out the exponent.

This seemed to work, but I'm looking for a more "mathy" numerical solution, preferably in some sort of pseudo-code.

Comment: (a) What form is the number in to start with? Is it a floating-point value, a decimal numeral, what? (b) Note that, if the number is a binary floating-point value, such numbers often have many digits when expressed exactly in decimal. For example, after `float x = .123;`, the value of `x` may actually be 0.123000003397464752197265625. Would you want to print “123000003397464752197265.625e-25”? (c) How do we decide whether to print 0, 1, 2, or 3 digits after the decimal point? Are we given a fixed number in each case, or do we have the whole range and choose based on something? What?

Comment: I have edited the OP in order to respond to Eric Postpischil's follow-ups.

Comment: As stated, this appears to be more of a mathematical question than a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a non-zero real number *x* whose expression in decimal has at most 18 significant digits.

Let *p*<sub>0</sub> be floor(log<sub>10</sub> |*x*|). This is the position of the leading significant digit of *x*, expressed as 0 for the one’s place, 1 for the ten’s place, 2 for the hundred’s place, and so on. (For this purpose, zeros after a decimal point and before the leading non-zero digit, as in “.00034”, are not counted as significant.)

Let *p*<sub>1</sub> be greatest integer such that 10<sup>*p*<sub>1</sub></sup> divides *x*. (Equivalently, *p*<sub>1</sub> is the greatest integer such that the modulo/remainder operation of *x* with 10<sup>*p*<sub>1</sub></sup> produces zero.) Then *p*<sub>1</sub> is the position of the trailing digit of *x*.

Let *n* be *p*<sub>0</sub>−*p*<sub>1</sub>+1. This is the number of significant digits in *x*.

*x* can be written with zero, one, two, or three digits after the decimal point by using *x*/10<sup>*p*<sub>1</sub></sup>, *x*/10<sup>*p*<sub>1</sub>+1</sup>, *x*/10<sup>*p*<sub>1</sub>+2</sup>, or *x*/10<sup>*p*<sub>1</sub>+3</sup> as the significand, respectively, and showing the exponent as *p*<sub>1</sub>, *p*<sub>1</sub>+1, *p*<sub>1</sub>+2, or *p*<sub>1</sub>+3, again respectively.

It is not clear to me from the question statement what choice of zero, one, two, or three digits is desired.

There may not be a good mathematical way to expression how to compute *p*<sub>1</sub> that is better than describing it as the greatest integer satisfying some property.